# Specify a platform for this target in your Podfile issue

Tags: firebase, terminal, cocoapods

I want to install some of Firebase pods. I followed all the step, but at last step I got error link below I mention.

After Executing the **pod install** command. I got the below error. Can someone please explain it to me? and how to fix it without affecting my project?

> [!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 14.2 on target TryFireBase because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform .

My podfile looks like:

```
*#* Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

*#* platform :ios, ‘9.0’

target ‘TryFireBase’ do

*#* Comment the next line if you don’t want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

*#* Pods for TryFireBase

pod ‘Firebase/Auth’ 

pod ‘Firebase/Firestore’ 

pod ‘Firebase/Storage’ 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `platform :ios, ‘10.0’` to the Podfile.

Recent Firebase releases require at least iOS 10.